# Borrar palabra dentro de fichero en MS-DOS

Tags: msdos

Agradezco de antemano la atención y ayuda.
Por favor si me podrían ayudar con esto.Si quisiera borrar de un archivo.bat una línea en específico que busco buscada con find como quedaría el programa, es que el comando find solo me devuelve un vaor 0 si lo encuentro y uno diferente sino.Con un for tal vez será posible?

```
TYPE ejemplo.txt | FIND /I "error" > NUL
IF %errorlevel%==0 RD(borrar la linea en la que está la palabra error)
```

Comment: Esta respuesta podria ayudarte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37438123/delete-a-specific-word-in-text-file-via-batch

Answer (score 0):

Solamente con la que tiene MS-DOS, dudo que sí.  Lo que quiere es algo como el programa sed (https://www.americati.com/doc/sed/sed.html) en *nix.  Probablemente hay una version hecha para MS-DOS, o por lo menos el código original.